# Live Preview of HTML and CSS changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to integrate Live HTML and CSS elements preview in a wordpress plugin.
The basic structure I have came up with is as follows but it does not work, may be a js error...

Here is the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        function GetHtml(){
                var html = $('.html').val();
                return html;
            }

        function GetCss(){
                var Css = $('.css').val();
                return Css;
            }

        $('.innerbox').live("keyup",function(){

            var targetp = $('#previewTarget')[0].contentWindow.document;
            targetp.open();
            targetp.close();

                var html = GetHtml();
                var css = GetCss();

                $('body',targetp).append(html);
                $('head', targetp).append('<style>' + css + '</style>');

            });
    });
</script>
```

Following is the html code..

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="box">
        <textarea class="innerbox html"></textarea>
        <textarea class="innerbox css"></textarea>

        <div class="innerbox preview">
            <iframe id="previewTarget">
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>hey</p>
                </body>
                </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If someone can suggest me any jquery plugin that enables live preview of CSS elements while editing then that would be highly appreciated...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using, `.live` has been removed from latest version of jquery.

Comment: I am using version 1.11.1

Comment: Mritunjay..  
I got the solution. It looks I need to use jquery version 1.7.1 for .live functionality.    Thanks for all  your help.  I do highly appreciate it.

Comment: The version `1.11.1` doesn't have `.live` function, see demo in answer.

Comment: Don't use an older version of jQuery, just use `on` instead, and in Wordpress jQuery is in no-conflict mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function has been removed from `jquery 1.9` so it is not present in `jquery1.11.1` use `.on` instead.

```
$('.innerbox').on("keyup",function(){...})
```

Everything else works fine.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/32/)